# Is the untyped .net DataSet a duck typed DTO?

Tags: .net, dataset, dto, duck-typing

Okay, I'm accessing the fields of a data row inside a data set using indexers, but let's consider this as just a syntactical feature. Would you go so far and call it a duck typed thing that is reduced to getters and setters, in other words a data transfer object?

Comment: It's certainly not a good example, and not one I'd give to someone who asked me what it meant- better examples in .NET are the foreach mechanism and the dynamic feature in C# 4.0.

Comment: I was not looking for an example, I was more or less thinking if the fact that an application heaviliy relies on such datasets might be a hint that using a more dynamic language is a good idea... or wait for c# 4.0 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. In fact, there's syntax in VB that makes it even more obvious. You can write:

```
Dim row As DataRow
row!Name = "Foo"     'same as row("Name")
```

Comment: oh, nice... never heard about that before (but I don't usually code in VB anyway)

Comment: same for me. And to be honest, this is one more reason for disliking VB ("VB.NET. Not since the Vikings named Greenland has there been such a marketing deception." - Juval Lowy)

Comment: @Marc, what's wrong with this particular feature? Note how it uses a distinct operator `!`, so there's no way to use this "accidentally". And I find it much more readable than canonical indexer form for cases like datasets and data readers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be.

A dictionary of strings can be one too.